# How to compare the current time and date with existing time fields and date from database?

Tags: mysql

I am having a table which contains start_time, end_time and date fields as a strings.

Table:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| vendor_id  | start_time  | end_time  | date          |
+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| 5000788324 | 09:00 AM    | 11:00 AM  | 17-03-2015    |
| 5000815782 | 10:00 AM    | 01:00 PM  | 17-03-2015    | 
| 5000482136 | 09:00 AM    | 01:00 PM  | 17-03-2015    |
| 6786788131 | 09:00 AM    | 11:00 AM  | 17-03-2015    | 
+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Now my requirement is to build a query that falls between date, start_time and end_time when compared with current time and date.

I tried this :

```
SELECT end_time, NOW() FROM vendor_no_del_time vda WHERE vda.vendor_id = "5000482136" AND (
    NOW() BETWEEN
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', vda.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
    AND 
    (STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', vda.end_time), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p'))
);
```

but no use. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right format for your data, and include `date` in the expression:

```
SELECT end_time, NOW()
FROM vendor_no_del_time vda
WHERE vda.vendor_id = 5000482136 AND (
    NOW() BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', vda.start_time), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i%p')) AND
                  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', vda.end_time), '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i%p')
);
```